# How to check checkbox in the "has_many :through" association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, has-many-through

I have these models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :product_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product, :through => :product_categories
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :product_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :product_categories
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The view:

```
- Category.order('title').each do |category|
  = check_box_tag :product_categories_ids, category.id, @product.product_categories.include?(category), :name => 'product[product_categories_ids][]'
  = label_tag :product_categories_ids, category.title
```

and when I print out `@product.product_categories`:

```
= @product.product_categories.inspect
```

the output is:

```
[#<ProductCategory id: 5, product_id: 9, category_id: 9, created_at: "2013-10-29 01:06:54", updated_at: "2013-10-29 01:06:54">, #<ProductCategory id: 6, product_id: 9, category_id: 7, created_at: "2013-10-29 01:06:54", updated_at: "2013-10-29 01:06:54">]
```

and I think that's the reason why the respective checkboxes are not checked here:

```
= check_box_tag :product_categories_ids, category.id, @product.product_categories.include?(category), :name => 'product[product_categories_ids][]'
```

How to update this part, that checks whether all the checkbox should be checked:

```
@product.product_categories.include?(category)
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
 = check_box_tag :product_categories_ids, category.id, @product.product_categories.include?(category), :name => 'product[product_categories_ids][]'
```

If I understand it correctly, you want to check if products categories array, includes a given catogory. If so, you should change

```
`@product.product_categories.include?(category)`
```

to

```
`@product.categories.include?(category)`
```